# SSRS basic arithmetic failures

Tags: reporting-services, vbscript, bids

I am sitting with a little weird issue - my `VBScript` in `SSRS` is failing at basic arithmetic.

Here is the scenario.

```
62 * 0.13 + 12 = 20.06
```

`SSRS` gets the answer

```
818
```

What I can see happening is that the `0.13` turns into `013`, which is `thirteen`. Here are the pieces of script I tried.

Note that the `First(Fields!PremiumAmount.Value, "PolicyDataset")` resolves to 62 in my current test case.

I have the following:

```
Try 1
= First(Fields!PremiumAmount.Value, "PolicyDataset") * 0.13 + 12

Try 2
= cDec(First(Fields!PremiumAmount.Value, "PolicyDataset") *0.13 +12)

Try 3
= First(Fields!PremiumAmount.Value, "PolicyDataset") * cDec(0.13) + 12)

Try 4
= cDec(First(Fields!PremiumAmount.Value, "PolicyDataset") * cDec(0.13) + 12)

Try 5
= cDec(First(Fields!PremiumAmount.Value, "PolicyDataset") * cDec("0,13") + 12)

Try 6
= cDec(First(Fields!PremiumAmount.Value, "PolicyDataset") * (13 / 100) + 12)

Try 7
Custom Code -> 

   Public Function MultiplyThirteenPercentPlusTwelve(input as Decimal) 
      return  input * 0.13 + 12
   End Function

In Report

= Code.MultiplyThirteenPercentPlusTwelve(First(Fields!PremiumAmount.Value, "PolicyDataset"))
```

All of these Resolve to 818. I am confused and amused at the same time. Are there any other tries I can take?

Comment: Are you sure its evaluating to 62 because I have tried above all approaches with `SQL SERVER 2008 R2` and same `SSRS` version it is working correctly. It's giving me `20.06`. Make sure your premium amount is int or numeric datatype. If your `PremiumAmount.Value` comes as `6200` then also it can give same issue.

Comment: If your PremiumAmount.Value comes as 6200 then also it can give same issue.

Comment: Try replacing the 12 with 12.0

Comment: Tickle me pink. I am using an XML data source. the 62 turned out to be 62.00, which got internally converted to 6200.

Add your answer @CoderOfCode, I will append the fix I got to this issue. Very ugly script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure `Fields!PremiumAmount.Value` is evaluating to the `62`.
 Because I have tried above all approaches with `SQL SERVER 2008 R2` and same `SSRS` version it is working correctly. It's giving me `20.06`. 
Make sure your `Fields!PremiumAmount.Value` is int or numeric datatype. 
If your `Fields!PremiumAmount.Value` comes as `6200` then also it can give same issue. Check your incoming data and its conversion.

Appended answer (from OP):

For some reason, the `62` that was referred to was pulling as `62.00`, and turned into `6200` in the calculation.

So the Following procedure was added. `62.00` had it's full stop replaced with a comma, converted as a decimal, then proceeded with the multiplication, followed by some basic decimal place formatting.

```
Format(cDec(Replace(First(Fields!PremiumAmount.Value, "PolicyDataset"), ".",",")) * 0.13D + 12.0D, "F2")
```